# Get unique rows from csv

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv file with over 5k rows with the following structure:

```
Source  Target  LinkId  LinkName    Throughput
==================================================
1       12      1250     link1250           5 //return
1       12      3250     link3250           14 //return
1       14      1250     link1250           5
1       14      3250     link3250           14
1       18      1250     link1250           5
1       18      3250     link3250           14
1       25      250      link250             2 //return 
2       12      2250     link2250           5 //return
2       12      5250     link5250           14 //return
2       14      2250     link2250           5
2       14      5250     link5250           14
2       18      2250     link2250           5
2       18      5250     link5250           14
2       58      50       link50             34
```

I would now like to filter the csv to display only the lines highlighted above, i.e, the csv should be filtered in such a way that there is only one entry per linkID irrespective of the other columns. So  I would expect something like this:

```
Source  Target  LinkId  LinkName    Throughput
==================================================
1       12      1250     link1250           5
1       12      3250     link3250           14
2       12      2250     link2250           5
2       12      5250     link5250           14
2       58      50       link50             34
```

and so on. Could someone suggest an easy way to do this in excel.

Comment: How to determine which result to return given two entries with the same LinkId? If no specific criteria, you can follow Kruger's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about keeping the duplicates, you can select all cells and go to Data>Remove duplicates. 
If you don't wanna delete any data, you can use a Pivot Table using the existing table as source.